# iphone, calling a method of different class in cocos2d layers?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have two classes, both are subclasses of CCLayer, 
I want to call a method of first class into second class, what should I code?

Comment: You need to explain your question a bit more. As far as I can see this isn't a cocos2d issue, this is an issue with your understanding of objective orientated programming. Can you explain a bit more and I can help you.

Comment: I really appreciate you for voting me down, but experience makes the difference, I got my answer

Comment: My downvote was for the lack of explaination in the question. There's no point in asking a question and not providing enough detail. I'm glad you got your answer though.

Comment: @Thomas, well it was not a big query, but next time I do explain all my questions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not providing much detail, but from my understanding of what you say, you need the following:

1. a selector in the public interface of your first class;
2. a pointer ivar in the second class that you will properly initialize so that it points to an instance of the first class;

In this way you will be able to call the first class' method from the second class.

Comment: [ob myMethod]; you want to say like this?